# SQL Is it posssible to do ORDER BY from MAX Column of antoher table?

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by

```
T1:
ID   
100
101
102

T2:
ID     OWNDATE   
100    1.1.2001
100    3.1.2001
101    2.1.2001
102    4.1.2001
```

I want something like `select * from T1`   but order by MAX own date column from T2 table?

Result will be

```
102
100
101
```

Is this possible? 
Thanks

Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join the two tables together on the ID, and order by the `OWNDATE` then.

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 on T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
ORDER BY T2.OWNDATE
```

**UPDATED:**

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [ID], MAX(OWNDATE) AS OWNDATE
    FROM T2
    GROUP BY [ID]
) T2 ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
ORDER BY OWNDATE DESC
```

Comment: This works ok this is solution. But sorry I have also one question more I am working this in some application where query starts with "SELECT T1.ID FROM T1 WHERE" and then I can write something!!! part before "SELECT T1.ID FROM T1 WHERE" I can not change, it must starts like that

Comment: So is it possible to change somehow your code to not to begin with FROM T1 INNER JOIN but with FROM T1 WHERE and to be applied for my needs? Sorry really for disturbing you

Comment: You can add a `WHERE` statement before the `ORDER BY` statement if you need to do any filtering on table `T1`.